# Cant make IL work. "Could destabilize the runtime" error

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, cil

I am trying few test codes for my another question on SO.

The code supposed to replicate:

```
(a, z) => a * b - Math.Log(z * b);
```

The code:

```
    static Func<int, int, double> IL_EmbedConst(int b)
    {
        var method = new DynamicMethod("EmbedConstIL", typeof(double), new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) });

        var log = typeof(Math).GetMethod("Log", new Type[] { typeof(double) });

        var il = method.GetILGenerator();

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, b);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_R8, b);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, b);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_R8, b);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, log);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Sub);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Func<int, int, double>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, double>));
    }
```

Using:

```
        var mul1 = IL_EmbedConst(5);
        double res = mul1(4,6);
```

Throws:

```
Operation could destabilize the runtime.
```

Cant see whats wrong (could be anything since last time I used asm-like language was 25 yrs ago)

Comment: Again. Use PEVerify after constructing IL.

Comment: Can't you use `Expression`s? They are usually much easier to work with and produce code that should be just as fast.

Comment: @leppie How do you use PEVerify with `DynamicMethod`?

Comment: @svick: You use `Reflection.Emit` instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the two places where you convert to `double`:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_R8, b);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_r8.aspx):

> **OpCodes.Conv_R8 Field**
>   Converts the value on top of the evaluation stack to float64.

That opcode takes no argument. Instead, simply use:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_R8);
```

The code runs fine and produces 16.5988026183378 as output.

Comment: That what I don't like about `ILGenerator`: it lets you specify blatantly invalid instructions.